# spring junit при тестах не срабатывает маппирование

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, junit

У меня есть класс `User`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class User implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Size(min = 3, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "LOGIN", nullable = false)
    private String login;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "owner", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Expense> myExpenses = new ArrayList<Expense>(0);

    public User()
    {
    }

    public Long getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getLogin()
    {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login)
    {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public List<Expense> getMyExpenses()
    {
        return myExpenses;
    }

    public void setMyExpenses(List<Expense> myExpenses)
    {
        this.myExpenses = myExpenses;
    }
}
```

И класс `Expense`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EXPENSE")
public class Expense implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "EXPENSE_ID")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")
    private User owner;

    public Expense()
    {
    }

    public User getOwner()
    {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(User owner)
    {
        this.owner = owner;
    }
}
```

Я тестирую через `junit` тест. Если найти класс `User` и сделать метод `getMyExpenses()`, то выдаёт пустоту, а при просмотре в отладчике значения переменных пишет "PersistentSet". Как в тестах включить, чтобы подтягивалось маппирование?

`HibernateTestConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan(basePackages =
{ "ru.make.alex.web.configuration" }, excludeFilters =
{ @Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = Configuration.class) })
@PropertySource(value =
{ "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateTestConfiguration
{
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory()
    {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[]
        { "ru.make.alex.web.model", "ru.make.alex.web.model.revenue" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        // sessionFactory.setAnnotatedClasses(User.class,
        // UserRole.class,Currency.class,Expense.class,OperationOnExpense.class,PackageOperation.class,
        // ProductCategory.class,RoutingOfTransaction.class);
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource
                .setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mytest?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8");
        dataSource.setUsername("lcomsys");
        dataSource.setPassword("lcomsys");
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties()
    {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect",
                "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "false");
        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s)
    {
        HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
        return txManager;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В тесте у меня стояла аннотация `@Transactional`, вот когда её убрал, то маппирование сработало, если у поля класса стоит `FetchType.EAGER`, а не `FetchType.LAZY`.
Мало ли может кому пригодится